# How to change font size in HTML string?

Tags: html, ios

I used an online HTML maker to get this

```
<p><span style=\"font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: x-large; color: #993300;\">A <strong>canyon</strong>&nbsp;is a deep, narrow valley with steep sides. &nbsp;Many canyons have rivers or streams running through them.</span></p>
```

But the font size is too small, and when I put a bigger size in the html maker and copy it to my code, it still shows up the same size.  I'm using it in a web view to show some text with customized formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an actual value in the `font-size` property, for example `font-size:48px`. If you put in a large enough number, it should show up larger than using `x-large`.

Answer (score 1):

why do you have you "\" before quote? Shouldn't it be :

```
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: x-large; color: #993300;">
```

Comment: because that whole line is part of a nsstring, needed to escape the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this.

The first way is deprecated so you should not use this method:

`<font size="5" face="arial" color="red">`

HTML is responsible for layout and thus including design and formatting is not good.

The second way is manipulation via css:

`h1 {font-size:250%}`

Instead of percentages, you can use px for pixels.

Good luck!