# Change font size for web view in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, html, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have implementing feed parsing & get the content as a string. Now, I am making html file through it programetically. Load that HTML in the Web view. My web View is the subview in Table View cell.

[image]

But Now i want to change the font size of web view content, so the user can see some detail .

My code for HTML generation is:

> ```
> NSString * postHTML=[[_parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"summary"];
>
>  NSString *close =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</body></html>"];
>
>     NSString *HTMLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", postHTML,close];
>
>     [Web_view loadHTMLString:HTMLString baseURL:nil];
>
> [cell.contentView addSubview:Web_view];
>
> return cell;
> ```

**How can i change font size of web view content??**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324548/how-to-change-font-size-in-html-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[myWeb loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:justify; font-size:45px;font-family:HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold;color:#0000;'>%@%@",postHTML,close] baseURL:nil];
```

you can set font size in font-size:size in code.

try this..let me know it is working or not!!!

Answer (score 4):

In UIWebView, you can use all HTML Tags while passing the data.

```
[WebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:justify; font-size:44px;font-family:HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold;color:#ffff;'>%@",Data] baseURL:nil];
```

Use above code where "Data" will be your content.

Thanks,

Hemang.

Answer (score 1):

set in your html

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                        @"<html> \n" "<head> \n"
                        "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                        "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                        "</style> \n"
                        "</head> \n"
                        "<body>%@</body> \n"
                        "</html>",@"Helvetica",[NSNumber numberWithInt:17],
                        @"<p><i>My data</p>"];
```

Comment: what is myweb? If it is web view, I try this but getting error because font methos is not found for web view.